# Why does Selector exist in swift

Tags: ios, swift, selector

Why did Apple choose to continue the use of the `Selector` type, with Swift being perfectly capable of sending the function.

So instead of doing this:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "showSomething:")
```

One could do:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer(showSomething)
```

and this also works if you have delegates:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer(delegate.showSomething)
```

Is there a reason that Apple chose to keep the sad implementation of a String to point to a function, instead of using the capabilities of Swift to the maximum?

Edit: example implementation of `showSomething`

```
func showSomething(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    println("showSomething triggered")
}
```

Comment: Only Apple knows. But there is strength in allowing a string to specify a method given that classes can be dynamically created.

Comment: for compatibility with Objective-C, I'd guess.

Comment: Notice that the selector in  `(target: self, action: "showSomething:")` is not the same as `(showSomething)`. The final ":" indicated a parameter is required.

Comment: @Zaph I know, but Swift can know what parameters are required when you give the function itself.

Comment: @Zaph The question code is perfectly fine, I'll add an example implementation of `showSomething` to show what I mean.

Comment: @vrwim You do not show passing the parameter, where is the call with the the parameter? Just make the code consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of legacy compatibility.

The API you used as an example were written in Objective-C, and still are. It is perfectly possible that Apple could take advantage of Swift's capabilities to produce more streamlined APIs, but it would require re-writing them natively in Swift, which for the vast array of existing frameworks that make up Cocoa & Cocoa Touch would take a massive amount of time and effort.

It is possible that Apple may add features to Objective-C that improve compatibility between the languages by taking advantage of newer Swift features, while preventing the need to rewrite the frameworks. For example, in Xcode 6.3 beta, they added the concept of "nullability" to Objective-C (see the release notes), which affects optionality of the Objective-C APIs when used in Swift code. Another example of where Swift could improve existing APIs is with default parameters... perhaps this could also be described in Objective-C APIs somehow?

I would not be surprised to see non-Objective-C (native Swift) frameworks being released by Apple in the future, but we're a little way off that yet.